# find string match from json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
{
    "appconfig": {
        "username" : "test",
        "password" : "testpassowrd"
    },
    "bot": [
         {
            "contains": [],
            "exact": ["hi","hy","hey","hlw"],
            "response": "hey there"
        },
        {
            "contains": [],
            "exact": ["gm","good morning","vgm"],
            "response": "good morning"
        }
    ],
    "blocked": [],
}
```

i am storing json snippet in son file and opening file during execution :

```
with open('/data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

i am looking forward to matching string with an exact array in JSON one by one in python. what is the best way possible using a lambda filter?

For example

```
user_msg = 'hi'
```

i have to match one by one in each exact array if a value exists send the response.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT : 1**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to get back every "exact" array that contains the value you specify?

Comment: i am looking forward to matching string with each array and get respective responsive.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that others can actually copy and use your proposed solution without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.  Please include your actual code too. `data` is a list, not the dictionary you expected, and without the code that sets data we can only hazard guesses, not provide you with an answer.

Comment: Side note: `else:` is not *required* when you use an `if` statement. You can safely drop the `else: pass` part, it does nothing and is just noise in your source code at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tom Robinson pointed out the solution which seems to be working well. But I would suggest to account for the complexity and the size of JSON as well. If the size is huge we need to look for solutions that load JSON as a stream, not as a file like https://github.com/henu/bigjson

Secondly, while comparing `in` is a simpler operation and easiest to point, but it is known to having taxing performance impact. Based on the size of the list, you may want to convert that into a set and try to find the value.

Lastly, the program seems to be working for dataset, however we need to account for missing keys, I would like to change the above to use dict.get() in place of dict['key'], So the finally extending the solution given by TOM may look like:

```
def getResponse(user_msg):
  with open('/data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
  for data_set in data.get("bot",{}):
    _extract = data_set.get("exact",None)
    if _extract and user_msg in _extract :
      return data_set.get("response",None)
getResponse(user_msg)
```

Using this we can avoid doing `key` checks.

Comment: This looks much more professional, whereas mine was more of a proof of concept. +1

Comment: Thanks for writing answer but still it's showing error.   File "/home/harsh/Documents/Instabot/instabot/examples/interact_DM.py", line 53, in <module>
    for data_set in data.get("bot",{}):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Converting the list to a set is O(N). Searching for an element in a list is also O(N), so you're not gaining anything by converting the list to a set. The only benefit you _might_ get from the conversion is removing duplicates (if there are any).

Comment: @SteveK, idea is to remove duplicate to speed up the process. Additionally @HarshManvar  there is an issue in JSON,  Three is a comma after "blocked": `[],`  which is causing an issue. Try the program after removing it.

Answer (score 2):

Through iterating over every possible data set, you can run checks every time like this:

```py
def getResponse(user_msg):
  for data_set in data["bot"]:
    if user_msg in data_set["exact"]:
      return data_set["response"]
getResponse(user_msg)
```

This assumes that data is already defined and in the global scope, whereas the next function reads the file internally:

```py
def getResponse(user_msg):
  with open('/data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
  for data_set in data["bot"]:
    if user_msg in data_set["exact"]:
      return data_set["response"]
getResponse(user_msg)
```

Comment: for data_set in data["bot"]: at this line it will give error like TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: for data_set in data["bot"][0]["exact"][0] something like this working.

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. When you `print(data)`, what does it output?

Comment: @HarshManvar Using the JSON you provided, data_set is just an element in the "bot" list. This code should work if your JSON is correct.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your reply i have tried by that way but using 3-4 loop solving my issue which is not good so finding better solution.

Comment: @TomRobinson updated question with attached screenshot.

Comment: @HarshManvar Can you confirm that the JSON you posted matches your bot.json file?

Comment: @SteveK That's started working now sorry my small mistake was there. thanks a lot for helping me out.